# How does back emf occur if a system can’t do work on itself?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, potential, electromagnetic-induction

If a coil is connected to a battery and the current starts up, the electrons have to be moving at a certain speed through the wire and therefore have a certain kinetic energy. But if they are moving through the coil of wire, they induce a back emf. This creates a current that is lower than expected (lower than V/R). So this seems to say that the electrons did negative work on themselves.

To me, it seems like we have a potential difference like in a situation where a battery is connected to a coil of wire, and so it’s sort of like a person falling through a gravitational potential difference. We expect this person to be falling at a certain acceleration. Likewise we expect the electron to be flowing at a certain rate. But because of the back emf, it is as if the electron is flowing slower than expected like a person is falling slower than expected.

This implies an opposing force, meaning negative work, so how was a system able to do work on itself (ie. That the electrons create a back emf, which is like an electric field in the opposite direction, but then that field does work on the electrons, implying a systems field does work on the system)?

Comment: If I consider a system to be both you and me, and I push on you, would you say the system did work on itself?

Comment: Why are you asserting that a system can't do work on itself? (I'm not implying that you're necessarily wrong.)

Comment: Your question seems unclear. A back emf is not produced if electrons are flowing through a coil at a constant rate. A back emf is only produced if the electronic current is changing with time.

Comment: IMO, the whole idea of "Back EMF" and voltages and currents that are different from "expected" serves no purpose except maybe to discourage too many people from seeking EE degrees. The very fact that the actual voltage/current differs from the "expected" proves that the expected is just a fantasy.  Why do we not _expect_ the voltage across a coil to obey $V=L\frac{dI}{dt}$ ?

Comment: Sorry edited it, a coil is attached to a battery so current begins to flow but the current is slower than “expected” due to the back emf

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy Re your comment to Aaron Stevens, see the following link about internal forces between parts of a system and how such forces cannot cause motion of the system as a whole. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Newt.html#nt3. In order for a net force to act on a system, and thereby do work on the system, the system must interact with something outside the system.

Comment: @BobD That comment was directed to OP. I know how centers of mass behave. I would say that what Aaron described constitutes a system "doing work on itself". Perhaps the conventional way of interpreting that phrase is that a system only does "work on itself" if it increases its own energy which is impossible.

Comment: I just meant that a back emf sort of seems like the electrons are creating an electric field in the opposite direction and then this field is doing work on them, but it doesn’t make sense for a field that a system generates to do work on that system.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy Sorry about that, I thought it was to Aaron. Anyway, I like your "increase its own energy" interpretation.

Comment: I would remove your whole "system doing work on itself" discussion. What we define to be the system is arbitrary. Really what you seem to be asking is "where does the energy go?" In the case of someone falling, you could say it is lost due to drag from the surrounding air. In the inductor case, we usually say the energy has "gone into making the magnetic field", although this might be an unsatisfactory answer for you, and I am somewhat unconvinced of it myself in the framework you have posed your question in.

Answer (score 0):

The energy that would've been part of the electrons' kinetic energy is instead stored in the electromagnetic field. Energy is still conserved and it is in this sense that the system does no work on itself.

Comment: The issue I have with this is that after some time, the current flows through the circuit as if the inductor is no longer part of the circuit. i.e. the current through the resistor is given by $V/R$. So this seems to say that now there is *more* energy than expected (using the terminology of the OP). The "expected" energy as well as the energy stored in the field. Perhaps you could expand on this?

Comment: @AaronStevens I don't know how to resolve this paradox.

Comment: I think the issue is in the OP's assumptions. The power supply will have to "push harder" to fight the back emf, thus putting more energy into the system than what is "expected". But I'm not fully convinced of my argument either

Answer (score 0):

The lost energy you're looking for is what is stored in the field as potential, and it's not lost (at least a major part of it) but preserved. When a current runs through a conductive wire, a magnetic field is created around each charged particle on the line-up, forming concentric circles with the strength diminishing radially. All that energy is absorbed back into the wire the moment the current creating the field is no more, this is what be observe and name self induction. Obviously there are looses, and since the field is theoretically assumed to propagate infinitely outward, some energy surely may be lost, buy not all of it.